# How to display data in template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

I want to generate qr code form qr_data in template:

{% qr_from_text qr_data size="S" %}

Why qr_data dont display any value in template ?

def qr_data(self, obj) - is in admin.py

def qr_data(self, obj):

```
    return format_html(
        '''
        ID: {}<br/>
        Size: {}<br/> 
        Producer: {}<br/> 
        Packed by: {}<br/> 
        Packed date: {}<br/> <br/>
        ''',

        obj.id,
        obj.size,
        obj.producer,
        obj.tested_by,
        obj.test_date,
    )
```

Or how to display several variable values in one in template ?

Comment: I added more information

Comment: Custom tags don’t go in `admin.py`. See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#custom-template-tags-and-filters) for full instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
return r'ID: {}<br/> Size: {}<br/> Producer: {}<br/>'.format(bj.id, obj.size, obj.producer)
```